# I can't get this function to give me all the prime numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to make a function to give the closest prime number to the number the person entered, and I'm not being successful. By the way, I'm starting to program now and for loops confuse me, any tips?
Here's the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Entry Mechanism
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Variables
        int n1, biggestPrime;

        System.out.print("Number: ");
        n1 = input.nextInt();

        biggestPrime = biggestPrime(n1);

    }

    public static int biggestPrime(int n1) {
        int biggestPrime = 0;
        boolean isPrime = true;

        if (n1 < 0)
            return 0;

        for (int i = n1; i == 0 && isPrime == false; i--) {
            if (i % n1 == 0) {

                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        return biggestPrime;
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect your function to return, and what line of code do you think makes that happen?

Comment: *The closest* means `x <= number` ? cause that's not closest but that's what you're doing...

Comment: Hmn, `isPrime` is true, the for loop wants `isPrime` to be false, that's never going to happen... Try to make `isPrime` false by default (`boolean isPrime = false`)

Comment: I know I need an external for loop for the function to return something, but I can't figure out what to put in it though...

Comment: `i == 0` should be `i != 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've supposed that you'll not try to find the biggest prime number of a prime number...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Entry Mechanism
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Variables
    int n1, biggestPrime;

    System.out.print("Number: ");
    n1 = input.nextInt();

    biggestPrime = biggestPrime(n1);

}

public static int biggestPrime(int n1) {
    int biggestPrime = 0;
    int num_max = 100000;

    if (n1 < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = n1; i< num_max; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
                System.out.println(j + " " + i);
                if (i==j) {
                    biggestPrime = i;
                    // break:
                    j = num_max;
                    i = num_max;
                }
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    break;
                }                      
            }
        }
    }
    return biggestPrime;
}
```

Comment: You do not really need this: 
`for (int j = 2; j < num_max; j++)`

this 

`for (int j = 2; j < sqrt(i); j++)`
is enough